# Why tailwind ui not rendered correctly in vue?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have installed tailwind according to the documentation in tailwindcss.com with vue in laravel. But its rendered like this below -

[image: tailwind ui form]

Why ?

**Configuration:**

1. Installed tailwindcss using commands

```
npm install -D tailwindcss
npx tailwindcss init
```

2)In `tailwind.config.js` added

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

3)In `input.css` added

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

4. For extra plugins ran this command

```
npm install @headlessui/vue @heroicons/vue
```

In main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import store from './store'
import App from './App.vue'
import './input.css'

createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .mount('#app')
```

Comment: Why not? Show your code and config that you have made

Comment: I have added my configuration and codes. Please check

Comment: I don't think there's enough. You don't have `.vue` in your tailwind config file, and no `app.js` provided. What document did you followed exactly

Comment: Try adding `input.css` in `main.js`. step 5 of [site](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite)

Comment: Added input.js in main.js. But where to add .vue in tailwind.config.js ?

Comment: I followed tailwindcss.com and tailwindui.com

Comment: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vue-3-vite

Answer (score 0):

Try using PostCSS

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss

Comment: Still not working. I have deleted all the packages of tailwind from package.json . Installed again from https://tailwindui.com/documentation#using-vue

Comment: And taking templates from https://tailwindui.com/#product-application-ui . Though its working but not rendered correctly. Images are becoming large. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

on tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    purge: 
        "./src/**/*.html",
        "./src/**/*.vue",
        "./src/**/*.jsx",
    ],
    //
};
```

it's simply adding the ones in the purge, after that, the vue is rendered properly, I think that the problem is that we haven't included vue on the tailwind configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tailwind.config.js files, one at the project level and the other at the vue directory. Copy and paste the following at the vue directory level

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{html,js,vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms')
  ],


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).